# Multipy number is between two numbers from a fix table

Tags: excel, numbers, between

Here is the challenge 
I have a bounce table where is I sell in between 2 values then I will get specific bounce.

**let say that the table is as follow:
between 1000 to 1500 I will get 2 points of bounce
1000 - 1500 = 2
1500 - 2000 = 4
(this table is fixed)**

What I want to do is, that when I write a number is the cell, then I need excel to check the number if it's between which value exactly and show me how many bounce points I must get.

[My table will be as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uD7mV.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), most notably [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Select the cell B2 and paste the below formula

```
=IF(AND(A2>=1000,A2<=1500),2,IF(AND(A2>1500,A2<=2000),4,""))
```

then copy and paste the cell B2 to other cells.